# Can multiple fact tables have the same structure?

Tags: database-design, dimensional-modeling

I'm designing the schema of a data base and I have two solutions :
the first is to use one fact table linked to multiple dimensions.
the second is to use multiple fact tables with same structure for each group (I have eight groups ) and all these fact tables are linked to the same eight dimensions.

I think the second solutions sounds good because I can avoid some joins to analyse per group.But I'm not sure about using multiple fact tables with same attributes for each group.
for example :
Fact1:
Id_Ap #|Id_cst#|Id_Ac#|Id_Dt#|Bp
Fact2:
Id_Ap#|Id_cst#|Id_Ac#|Id_Dt#|Bp
.. Fact 8 : the same.

Comment: It might help if you gave some explanation of the table structure and what it is going to be used for to help provide a better answer.

Comment: Please check out my profile for a few articles on how to ask questions here. I can't understand your question as it stands. We need more info. p.s. welcome to the forum :-)

Comment: Thanks Vérace, As I've explained in a comment to the answer of Joe W, I can't decide between having one fact table that has all the informations about costs or creating multiple fact tables for each group of cost ( eight groups), these fact tables will have the same attribute names. On one hand having multiple fact tables will give more performance when analyzing per group of cost ( avoiding join with another table to get the cost group). On the other hand if I want to analyze the total I will have to make multiple queries on each fact table corresponding to each group of cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and depending on what you are doing that might be a very good idea. I will use a request table as an example.

Request comes in and goes to a submitted request table. After it gets processed it moves to a pending table. If it gets approved it moves to an approved/completed table. If it gets canceled it gets moved to a canceled table. Having the same table structure allows for the system to easily move data around and for users to easily select data from any of the tables.

While this can also be done with a status column the design of the database and amount of data could make it more desirable to have a separate table for each state.

Comment: thanks for your response and the example you gave. In my situation I have some cost groups which have cost elements. So each cost element belongs to a certain cost group. To design my database either I will put all the cost elements into a single fact table or create multiple fact tables for each cost group which contains cost elements that belong to this cost group but each of these fact tables will have the same structure( same attribute name). What do you think is the best solution in my case ?